# Airflow v2 Create Dynamic Task Mapping based on input config from UI

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x, airflow-taskflow

I have a dag with an input Param like so:

```
@dag(
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    schedule=None,
    params={
        "param1": Param(
            ["all"],
            "Select from the list of options.",
            type="array",
            title="Param 1",
            examples=["all", 'half'],
        )
    }
)
def updateDAG():
...
```

I want to create dynamic task mapping based on the number of elements in the input list. I.e. Maximum of 2 tasks and minimum of 1.

I know that I can use the `.expand()` feature to run a task N times:

```
links = task1.override(task_id="run_task").expand(arg1='{{ dag_run.conf.param1 }}')
```

The above reads `'{{ dag_run.conf.param1 }}'` as a string and creates a task for each character in the string. But I want to pass in the input parameter like `["all"]` as given in the input from UI.

Answer (score 0):

Have a separate task that uses [get_current_context](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html#airflow.operators.python.get_current_context) to retrieve params and write it into XCom.

```py
@task
def get_params():
    return get_current_context()['params']['param1']

links = task1.override(task_id="run_task").expand(arg1=get_params())
```

Comment: This is the correct workaround. But I wanted to know if there is an airflow native way to get context at DAG level.

Comment: I'm afraid not.